# Efficient way to read a small file from a very large Zip file in Java

Tags: java, zip, zipinputstream

I was wondering if there is any efficient way to read a small file from a very large zip. I am not interested in any other file in the zip except a small file called inventory.xml.

To be exact, the zip file resides in artifactory. So I don't want to download entire file into my disk as well. Here is what I have now.

```
URL url = new URL("artifactory-url");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    int status = con.getResponseCode();
    if (status != 200) {
        System.out.println("Unable to find the artifact : " + url.toString());
        return bugs;
    }
    try (ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(con.getInputStream())) {
        ZipEntry entry;
        while ((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (entry.getName().contains("inventory.xml")) {
                //do something here
            }

        }
    }
```

Another query is, If I know the co-ordinates of the file, would it help?

Comment: is this code not efficient ?

Comment: @DhanasekaranDon   it loops through each zipentry and if its a huge zip file with a lot entries, it takes a good amount of time.

Comment: Nothing you can do about that. It's a sequential format. Make sure you break out of the loop after you've dealt with the file you want.

Comment: `con.getInputStream()` gets the complete file so you cannot just get parts of the file. So as @user207421 said, you cannot do anything about that.

Comment: @Renis1235  `getInputStream()` returns the input stream. You then have to read data from it, as much as you need. You haven't downloaded the whole file. Just the part you read.

Comment: @user207421 I am breaking out if i find the required file. the problem is there are huge files which doesn't have the particular file which I am looking for. So its kind of looping until the end for that file.

Comment: @grigorymendel Very good, so there is nothing you can do, except find a way not to download files that don't have what you're looking for in them, or have the individual files available at the server instead of a huge ZIP file, which isn't much use to anyone really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many of you mentioned, the code mentioned in the question itself is probably the most efficient solution. Thank you for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

ZIP files store their directory at the end of the file, so *if* you have some way to randomly access the contents of the file you could do this.

However, that's a big "if": it requires Artifactory to support byte-range GETs, and requires you to re-implement (or find/adapt) the code to read the directory structure and retrieve a file from the middle of the archive.

If you need to do this frequently, a far better solution is to change the process that puts those files in Artifactory in the first place. If it's packaged in a JAR that's produced by Maven or another build tool, then it's a simple matter of extracting the files into their own dependency.